# How do I findall('dt') without returning new line ('\n')?

Tags: python, parsing, python-re, findall

I'm not sure what to try here. I'm running an example code from a tutorial that returns all the s&p500 tickers from a wikipedia table.

```
import bs4 as bs
import pickle
import requests
import re

def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'constituents'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]: 
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text #here's the problem I want to fix
        tickers.append(ticker)
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    return tickers

save_sp500_tickers()
```

The problem is it's also returning '\n' for each row, which I wasn't expecting because it isn't explicitly written in the web source text.

I could just run another loop to get rid of it but I was wondering if you can use a re in (findAll('td')) to do it.
I know you'd just use '.' re to read all characters except for new line, but I don't know how to implement it into the line because findAll('td') is already doing the job of finding what's inside of &lt td htmlspecialchars td> ... </td automatically, so I assume I can't just shove the re in there.

Comment: can you remove it with `.rstrip()`?

Comment: Yeah that did it, I was way overthinking it. Thank you!